# How to marshal an array structure containing a matrix of char

Tags: c#, c++, marshalling, com-interop

Based on the following C++ Header content:

```
typedef struct {
char    myVar[30][50];
}MyStruct;

extern "C" int   WINAPI  MyFunction(MyStruct *Configuration,int *CfgSize);
```

I have looked for many examples over the internet but none uses a **matrix variable** inside a **struct array** as a parameter.
Can someone please tell me How to consume this function in C#?

Comment: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2010/02/interop-multidimensional-arrays-of.html

Comment: @DarkFalcon it is still not working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to marshal this array member you just need to flatten it to the 1500 elements that it represents

```
[StructLayoutAttribute(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct MyStruct {

    /// byte[1500]
    [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst=1500, ArraySubType=UnmanagedType.I1)]
    public byte[] myVar;
}
```

Do make sure to initialize the `myVar` array though manually when using in C#